# how to run eclipse android emulator via visual studio

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, visual-studio, vs-android

Hi is it possible to run or communicate eclipse android emulator via MS visual studio?
If yes please help me or state ways how to set up possible solution.

Comment: no I'm not using mono, all I want to do is I have my codes in C++ and I want to run the output into the eclipse android emulator. Is this possible?  I try this one but no luck.

http://www.ceveni.com/2009/12/run-android-emulator-from-command-line.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mono for Andriod.
We can run the app as usual in Visual Studio by choosing

> Debug > Start Without Debugging (or Start Debugging to run with the debugger attached).

or Simply press F5 in your “Mono for Android” Visual Studio project.

Visual Studio will launch the Select Device dialog Selecting `Start emulator image` in this dialog and it will open a list of available emulators:

[image]

When we choose the emulator we want to run and then click OK, Mono for Android launches the emulator. After it starts up, the emulator will appear in the Running devices list

From the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html):

*The recommended way to develop an Android application is to use Eclipse with the ADT plugin...*

---

Added new Solution based on the comments

[vs-android](https://code.google.com/p/vs-android/) is intended to provide a collection of scripts and utilities to support integrated development of Android NDK C/C++ software under Microsoft Visual Studio.

Currently vs-android only works under Visual Studio 2010. Earlier versions lack the MSBuild integration with the C/C++ compilation systems.

The only required component is the Android NDK. Neither Cygwin, Java, nor the full Android SDK are needed to compile and link C/C++ code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, but what I want to do is run my application in a visual studio (my codes in c++) using the eclipse android emulator.

Comment: not really but different problem, when installing Ant Setup in https://code.google.com/p/vs-android/wiki/Installation I got an error ("F:\apache-ant-1.8.3\bin\ant.bat" exited with code 1.)

Comment: You have to either:

-Attach an Android device, with USB debugging enabled on it
OR Start a virtual Android device from the Android SDK's 'SDK Manager'.